# Cheap narrow field lens to detect red laser light?

Tags: laser

I want to monitor a red laser dot at a distance, say max 50m. I'm looking for a cheap lens array of sorts that I can place in front of a light detector (haven't an idea yet what I'm going to use yet - fast photodiode?)

My guess is that I'll have a lens with a red filter between the lens and the detector and then I'll read the light intensity. The red laser is the standard ones that can be bought at any gadget and toy store. Do they have a lens array in them that can be used in reverse?

Any ideas? Out of the box thinking?

Comment: What kind of field of view are you looking at? What percentage of said field will be the laser dot?

Comment: Why do you need a lens?

Comment: This is not an alectrical engineering question

Comment: RE on hold:  Why such a narrow view of electronics?  A photodiode is about electronics.. isn't efficient coupling of light into the PD also electronics?  I mean all our sensor's/ actuators have to couple to the outside world.  This is a question about how to do that.

Comment: This one was easy for me.  A shaft needs to couple to a turbine,but you wouldn't call that coupling electrical engineering.  If the question were how to adjust the brightness of the laser, or hoe to control a servo that kept the laser pointed at the photodiode, that woupd be different

Comment: Hi @ScottSeidman, OK for me if the shaft goes to some sensor that is measuring the rotation of the turbine, then how the entire mechanical chain is made can effect the workings.  And maybe we'd talk about anti-backlash gears or something.  I'm mostly interested in building instruments.  There are electronic bits, mechanical things, optics, maybe some thermo or other physics involved.  Good design involves understanding of the entire thing.  And the lines between electronics and other aspects is fuzzy (to me).

Comment: @GeorgeHerold -- Totally agree about your comments on design, I just don't think EESE is the place to cover ALL of it.  There should at least be some question about the EE portions of the design for a question to find a home here, and this question has no question about any of the EE issues. http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/60453/engineering is in commitment phase

Answer (score 2):

You'll want a lens at least as big as your laser spot size at 50m.  (How are you holding everything steady?  You don't want the beam bouncing around.)  If this is in daylight you'll also want a tube/ shroud around the photo diode to reduce all the stray light getting in. (lens well inside the tube)  A filter could help also.  If money is no object an interference filter centered around the laser wavelength is nice.

What's the application?

Comment: For those who want to help, thanks for the feedback. Yes, this is all about electronics. If this forum is just about the electronics side of the circuit and not how you would get it to work in real life situations, then I'm sorry...

Comment: The sensor and the laser would sit next to each other. The sensor will pick up the reflection of the laser light. What I want is for the sensor to view as much light as possible from where the laser dot is shining. Maybe the long tube approach might work. I'll test it. What I was hoping for is a cheap minature telephoto lens type setup that I could use - maybe some light sensor tube in reverse.

Comment: @andrebruton,  Hmm OK now we need more.  (you can maybe edit your original question to include the additions.)  Is this is in a dark room? broad daylight?  Do you have a corner cube reflector for the laser?  Or you just want to detect the scattered light?  Though you haven't mentioned ranging, you might want to read some articles about LIDAR and see how they  detect the laser.